# Workflow application.PersistableIdle event not firing

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Hi I am new to Windows Workflow. This may be very easy, but I am stuck on this from long.
I have a state machine workflow, in which i have a workflow host class.
Persistence is not working in this code. While debugging pointer never goes to application.persistableIdle event.

I use custom input argument, for which I have set as Serializable.

below is my code of the host class:

```
 static InstanceStore instanceStore;
    static AutoResetEvent instanceUnloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static Activity activity = new Activity1();
    static Guid id = new Guid();
    static int intContractHeaderKey;
   static  Contract contract = new Contract();

 public ContractActivityHost(Guid wfid, Int32 contractHeaderID)
    {
        SetupInstanceStore();

        StartAndUnloadInstance(contractHeaderID);
        if (intContractHeaderKey > 0)
        {
            LoadAndCompleteInstance(id, intContractHeaderKey);
        }
    }

    static void StartAndUnloadInstance(Int32 contractHeaderID)
    {

        contract = new Contract();
        //var objContract = new object();

         var input = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                {"TheContract", contract}                                
                            };
         input.Add("ContractHeaderKey", contractHeaderID);


         WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(activity, input);


        application.InstanceStore = instanceStore;


        //returning IdleAction.Unload instructs the WorkflowApplication to persists application state and remove it from memory  
        application.PersistableIdle = (e) =>
        {
            return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
        };

        application.Unloaded = (e) =>
        {
            instanceUnloaded.Set();
        };

        //application.Idle = (e) =>
        //    {
        //        //application.Unload();
        //        instanceUnloaded.Set();

        //    };


        //This call is not required 
        //Calling persist here captures the application durably before it has been started
        application.Persist();
        id = application.Id;

        application.Run();

        instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();

        //application.Unload();
        //contract = (Contract)objContract;

        intContractHeaderKey = contract.ContractID;
    }

    static void LoadAndCompleteInstance(Guid wfid, Int32 contractHeaderID)
    {
        //string input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!contract.ContractWFPause)
        {
            contract.FireContract(contract.ContractID);

            WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
            application.InstanceStore = instanceStore;

            application.Completed = (workflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs) =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("\nWorkflowApplication has Completed in the {0} state.", workflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs.CompletionState);
                strWFStatus = "Completed";
            };

            application.Unloaded = (workflowApplicationEventArgs) =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("WorkflowApplication has Unloaded\n");
                strWFStatus = "Unloaded";
                instanceUnloaded.Set();
            };

            application.Load(wfid);


            instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private static void SetupInstanceStore()
    {
        instanceStore =
            new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WorkflowInstanceStore;Integrated Security=True;");

        InstanceHandle handle = instanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
        InstanceView view = instanceStore.Execute(handle, new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        handle.Free();

        instanceStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
    }
```

I have been trying to resolve this from long time, but not sure where I am missing anything. I have gone through couple of sample applications and changed my code to match the flow and logic, but still it does not work.
After application.persist, record is inserted in [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] view.
But debug pointer does not move beyond instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();
it actually goes to idle state. if I uncomment application.idle event, it goes in that event code.

Any help to resolve this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: lol, a familiar pattern, blocking the thread while the WA executes.  I've made a version of this myself.  You've got a lot of statics and you're dealing with types that are inherently multithreaded.  That's a smell, definitely.  Make that class completely instance based (i.e., get rid of all the static stuff).  Not sure if that is involved, but it is a start.  Still reading.

Comment: Yeah, you're doing some weird stuff in there.  Instantiating things multiple times, for example.  I see you've taken this code partly from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780144.aspx), but have you checked out the [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807516.aspx) from which the (incomplete) example is taken?  You may be able to adapt the code from it and fix your issues.

Answer (score -1):

Please check If you have added the below details

```
instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WFPersistenceDb"].ConnectionString);

StateMachineStateTracker.Promote(this.instanceStore);
```